# Find urls and make it clickable in reactJs/javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink

I go through many stack-overflow questions but none of it works.

> find URLs and on click open in new tab

let's say I've this string:  **this is google url click on it : www.google.com**. On website instead of showing this string directly I want to find url from string and see as a clickable url.

like this : **this is google url click on it : https://www.google.com/**

what I've tried from my side is :

```
linkify("this is google url click on it : https://www.google.com/");

linkify = inputText => {
var replacedText, replacePattern1, replacePattern2, replacePattern3;

//URLs starting with http://, https://, or ftp://
replacePattern1 = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gim;
replacedText = inputText.replace(replacePattern1, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>');

//URLs starting with "www." (without // before it, or it'd re-link the ones done above).
replacePattern2 = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;
replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern2, '$1<a href="http://$2" target="_blank">$2</a>');

//Change email addresses to mailto:: links.
replacePattern3 = /(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.])+@[a-zA-Z\_]+?(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+)/gim;
replacedText = replacedText.replace(replacePattern3, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');

return replacedText;


};
```

this code is peace of one of stack-overflow question.

result of this code is :

```
this is google url click on it : <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank"> https://www.google.com/ </a>
```

But I need final output in this manner :

**this is google url click on it : https://www.google.com/**

I've tried **anchorme.js** but got same output.

steps to implement anchorme.js

```
import anchorme from 'anchorme';

anchorme("this is google url click on it : https://www.google.com/");
```

but  output is same.Then tried linkify reactJs package [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-linkify) but it's return object and crash application.

**linkify implementation **

```
import Linkify from 'react-linkify';

<Linkify>this is google url click on it : https://www.google.com/ </Linkify>
```

it's output is big object with keys like props, keys etc.

Comment: how do you use `linkify`?

Comment: @dfsq I tried to use linkify but it's return object. if you can provide example it'll be helpful.

Comment: you need to post an example of you code, then it's easy to fix it

Comment: @dfsq add code on linkify implementation

Answer (score 5):

Use Linkify-react to make links clickable use the below syntax to customize links in your format

```
const componentDecorator = (href, text, key) => (
    <a className="linkify__text" href={href} key={key} target="_blank">
      {text}
    </a>
  );

<Linkify componentDecorator={componentDecorator}>
....
</Linkify>   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Properties Doesn't Work

properties is removed in latest linkify version so use it like this

```
<Linkify
    componentDecorator={(decoratedHref, decoratedText, key) => (
        <a target="blank" href={decoratedHref} key={key}>
            {decoratedText}
        </a>
    )}
>
```

See this for further reference
https://github.com/tasti/react-linkify/issues/96#issuecomment-628472955

Answer (score 2):

found a solution using **linkify**.

```
import Linkify from 'react-linkify';

 <Linkify properties={{ target: '_blank', style: { color: 'blue' } }}>{message}/Linkify>
```

Comment: The properties prop has recently been removed. However there are other answers to this question that show the workaround to style the links as of 2021/22.

Comment: @Dhaval Can tell us that above specified properties {{ target: '_blank', style: { color: 'blue' } }} is woring fine? Because link is going to open in same tab and also color not changing

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        this is google url click on it :{" "}
        <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
          {" "}
          https://www.google.com/
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHF2J.png)

Comment: you don't understand the issue. I'm not looking for this.

Comment: Screenshot of my obtained output is posted along with the code. Have a look and let me know if this was your issue

Comment: I can't use this code because my string is coming from backend APIs and I don't know does string has URL or not so how can I use this code. you're new on site so I'm not going to give you down point.

Comment: string contains URL, email, phone number and for all I need deferent logic and this code defiantly not work for my case.

Comment: You never mentioned in the question that your url comes from a backend code. That's why I gave you direct answer. Sorry for my wrong answer, it happened because I didn't actually understand from your question, what you were looking for. Apologies from my side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-anchorme](https://github.com/potty/react-anchorme):

```ts
import React from 'react'
import { Anchorme } from 'react-anchorme'

const SomeComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Anchorme>Lorem ipsum http://example.loc dolor sit amet</Anchorme>
  )
}
```